# Sum Expression Aggregate Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am rewriting this question because Gordon Linoff told me it might come off as rude if I edited my other one -- so this isn't a duplicate, just a correction.

I am trying to write a code that will sum the prices of all the orders that come up when I fill out the query. For example, if I enter the ID range 1-60, I want there to be a sum column created that then sums up all the prices of ID's 1-60.

I thought it would be simple enough to just create a SUM(.....) AS Exp 1, but it tells me that there is a problem with the ID and aggregate function.

I want to be able to see the individual prices, as well as a new column with the sum of all these prices. I plan on adding some more columns of data into the table later on.

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT table.ID, table.Price, SUM(table.Price) AS Exp 1 
FROM table
WHERE table.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Add a `Group By` with the columns that aren't being aggregated.

Comment: You should delete your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a concept error with your aggregate statement. When you run this query, the WHERE clause will evaluate first to exclude all IDs that are not between your user specified start and end points. Then, you missed the GROUP BY clause to tell it what needs to be grouped. Eliminate the table.Price field, otherwise you will be getting unique records for each price which is not what you want.

```
SELECT t.ID, SUM(t.Price) AS Price_Summary
FROM table t
WHERE t.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Also, aliases will help improve readability.

**EDIT**

I think this might be what you are trying to get to, but I'm still unclear.

```
SELECT t.ID, SUM(t.Price) AS Price_Summary, 
    (SELECT SUM(t2.Price) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID) AS Total_Price
FROM table t
WHERE t.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID
GROUP BY t.ID
```

This will give you a result set with all of the IDs, a sum of the price of everything with that ID, and then a total sum. So it would look something like this:

```
ID | Price_Summary | Total_Price
1    10              60
2    30              60
3    20              60
```

Comment: this works perfectly, but I am trying to sum the prices of every one of the ID's (in order to get my total amount of money). If I wanted to do this, would I get rid of the GROUP BY command so that it just shows one giant total in one cell in a separate column?

Comment: Correction to my comment above, I tried to simply delete the group by command, and it gave me the aggregate error for the ID. I thought this would work, but I guess I was mistaken. Do you have any advice?

Comment: To get a total, delete t.ID from the SELECT clause and remove the GROUP BY clause completely.

Comment: Sorry to be so complicated, but this is the problem. I want to see each ID, with each Price for the ID, then another column with the total sum of all the Prices.

Comment: So you want to see the total price of everything repeated down for every item? That seems redundant.

Comment: Not exactly. The sheet has my receipts for everything for the month, each one with an ID and a price. I basically want to be able to see a list of the ID's, their prices, and a third with the total of all the prices for the month -- so there is only one total.

Comment: This is why sample data output is so important in your question. Look at my edit in my answer and let me know if that is not what you are after.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you and sorry for my novice mistakes.